# Change the file settings.php of a drupal site via a user interface

Tags: drupal, user-interface, settings

Is it possible to create a user interface that ask the user to give the data base name and parameters: username, password...and create a new data base array in the file settings.php?

Comment: Hi usually u don't do this but i suppose u can persist those newly added dbs in a seperate file add them to the global validable $database in hook_boot

Comment: can u clarify a little more your solution?

Comment: if u want to change databases within ur modules and not during boot do the following. each time use gives a new database connection store it in a file. then write a hook function called hook_boot.since $database variable is a global variable u can alter it within ur hook functions. but to change db during ur boot strap u can look at fixture module,Its a test cases module,they change dbs when u run simpletest , u can use their logic

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard module/functionality for this.
Usually, settings.php is protected file and read-only for security purpose. You can change file mode, parse file in php code and rewrite it. But, if you need only "create a new data base array", i I suggest you realize include-functionality.
Create folder like "settings.d" nearby to settings.php. Add to settings.php code like this (not tested)

```
$dir    = 'settings.d';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $filename) {
  if ($filename == '.' ||  $filename == '..') {
    continue;
  }
  include $filename;
}
```

This code is not tested, but i think you understand conception.
After this, you can create/delete/modify configurations in settings.d without parsing original settings.php.